# Is there support to compression or decompress .xz files in LZMA?

Tags: hadoop, compression, native, native-code, lzma

1) I want to write a decompression codec for hadoop which can decompress .xz files with lzma2.

2) I come to know that LZMA2 compression library supports .xz format.

3) But recently I came across a lzma codec for hadoop(in a facebook/hadoop codebase) which can decompress .xz files, so I was wondering if this codec is based upon native implementation of lzma or lzma2?

So basically i want to know if lzma supports .xz format for compression and decompression?

Comment: The output from the original implementation of LZMA was called .lzma. When the new LZMA2 algorithm was introduced, they simple called the resulting format .xz vecause it did not have binary compatibility with LZMA1. So yes, if you have a codec that decompresses .xz files, then it uses LZMA2.